# 'stack smashing detected' error

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a assignment, I am to use a multidimensional array and use the "iomanip" library to correctly output the multiplication tables from 1 to 12 (kind of like how school notebooks have them on the back). Though I am getting the desired output, right under the correct array indices, I am getting this error

```
***stack smashing error detected*** : <unknown> terminated
```

My code is not at all done, this is only my second semester in CS. In the code below, I am first testing an algorithm for creating the table inside the main function before porting it to a stand alone function, as our professor want to implement modular or functional programming. It goes as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int multTable[12][12];
    int tester;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
        { 
            multTable[i][j] = i * j;
        }
    }

    tester = multTable[2][3];//this displays the correct number, 6
    cout << tester << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much in advance. 
(PS: an explanation and some tips are the only things needed, I want to do my HW myself.)

Answer (score 2):

An array of size 12 will have elements from index 0 to index 11. You should be doing this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    { 
        multTable[i][j] = i * j;
    }
}
```

Earlier, you were starting from 1 to 12, which meant that when you tried to insert a value at the 12th position, you were attempting to insert the value outside the memory allocated for the array.

Answer (score 1):

C/C++ arrays start at index zero.

Instead if iterating from 1 to 12 you must iterate from zero to 11.

Writing to `multTable[12][12]` will write to memory outside of your function's stack space corrupting it. This is "stack smashing".

Answer (score 0):

Array indexing in C++ is zero based (first element has index `0`), not one-based.

Accessing `multTable[12]` or (through it) `multiTable[12][j]` in all iterations of the inner loop in your code gives *undefined behaviour*.  The meaning of "undefined", in the C++ standard, is essentially that "the standard does not define what happens as a result".

Practically, writing a value using invalid array indices overwrites some memory that does not exist, as far as your program is concerned.   Stack smashing (meaning your program has trashed the stack allocated to it at startup by the operating system) is one possible effect of that - but not the only one.

To correct the problem change the loops to reduce the indices by `1`.   For example - change the start and end conditions in both loops.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) 
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    { 
        multTable[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
    }
}
```

Note that the assignment in the loop body is also changed.

Because the array indexing is shifted, you will also need to change how the value is accessed by reducing both indices.

```
tester = multTable[1][2];//this displays the correct number, 6
```

In modern C++, it is generally preferable to use standard containers, rather than raw arrays.   I'll leave that as an exercise.

All of the above is described in introductory textbooks on C++.   It would be a good idea to read introductory material, rather than obviously assuming you know (e.g. by analogy with another programming language that works differently).

Answer (score 0):

I have taken into consideration what was pointed out and corrected my mistake. Here is the final code, it works just as I want it to:

```
/*
 * This program creates an array of size 12X12 two displpay the multiplication tables
 * from 1-12, uses 2 functions, one function called multTable() that takes in no
 * parameters and the other function is displayTable(), which takes in an array
 * as a parameter and outputs the array in matrix format using the iomanip
 * library.
 */
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

static const int COL = 12;
static const int ROW = 12;


void multTable();//multTable() function prototype of type void
void displayTable(int arr1[][ROW]);//displayTable() function prototype



int main() 
{
    cout << "This program outputs the multiplication tables from 1-12:\n\n";
    multTable();//function call to multTable()

    return 0;
}

void multTable()//function definition for multTable, takes in no formal parameters
{
    int table[COL][ROW];//declares an array of size COL X ROW
    int tester;

    for(int i = 0; i < ROW ; i++)//loop through each row
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <  COL; j++)//loop though each element in each row
        { 
            table[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);//since arrays are 0 indexed, i and j must be incremented by 1, in order
                                           //to achieve desired value of element
        }
    }
    displayTable(table);//function call to displayTable() with table as actual parameter
}

void displayTable(int arr1[][COL])//function definition fror displayTable(), takes in
                                  //an array of type int as its formal parameter
{
    for(int a = 0; a < 12; a++)//loop through each row
    {
        for(int b = 0; b < 12; b++)//loop through each column
        {

            cout << left << setw(5) << arr1[a][b];//prints all contents of the ath row, left justified with
                                                  //with a width of 5
        }
        cout << endl;//starts the bth row on a new line per iteration
    }
}
```